# Merge two CSV files into one

Tags: csv, powershell

I have two CSV files that don't have any unique identifiers. The number of rows of both files is *always the same*. I want to merge them as it is (the 2nd CSV as additional columns into the 1st CSV).

**Content of file1.csv:**

```
Server,Info  
server1,item1  
server1,item2  
server1,item3  
server2,item1  
server2,item2  
server2,item3  
server3,item1  
server3,item2  
server3,item3
```

**Content of file2.csv:**

```
Items,ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC  
item#1:,aa,jj,ss  
item#2:,bb,kk,tt  
item#3:,cc,ll,uu  
item#1:,dd,mm,vv  
item#2:,ee,nn,ww  
item#3:,ff,oo,xx  
item#1:,gg,pp,yy  
item#2:,hh,qq,zz  
item#3:,ii,rr,ab
```

**Expecting output of csv file:**

```
Server,Info,Items,ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC  
server1,item1,item#1:,aa,jj,ss  
server1,item2,item#2:,bb,kk,tt  
server1,item3,item#3:,cc,ll,uu  
server2,item1,item#1:,dd,mm,vv  
server2,item2,item#2:,ee,nn,ww  
server2,item3,item#3:,ff,oo,xx  
server3,item1,item#1:,gg,pp,yy  
server3,item2,item#2:,hh,qq,zz  
server3,item3,item#3:,ii,rr,ab
```

I have search intensively in the net, but couldn't find any solution... Would really appreciate if someone can provide me some answers here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read both CSV files, iterate over it using a for-loop and use a format string to join them together. Finally, write the new file back using the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
$file1 = Get-Content 'Path_to_file1.csv'
$file2 = Get-Content 'Path_to_file2.csv'

$content = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $file1.Length; $i++)
{
    '{0},{1}' -f $file1[$i].Trim(), $file2[$i].Trim()
} 

$content | out-file 'Path_to_file3.csv'
```

Comment: Martin solution is awesome you can add this line below to make csv readable 

`import-csv -path "Path_to_file3.csv" | export-csv -path "mergednew.csv" -Delimiter "," -notypeinformation`

Comment: @Martin, thank you so much for the solution, adding the line Owl provided it works perfectly :)

Comment: @Owl, thank you so much for the additional line to make Martin's solution works perfectly :)